# Android TV not starting correct activity

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-tv

I have an app that should run on both phone and TV. In the manifest, I'm specifying the phone's launch activity with

```
<activity
    android:name=".view.phone.MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and the TV's launch activity with

```
<activity
    android:name=".view.leanback.MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Instead of filtering between LAUNCHER & LEANBACK_LAUNCHER, on either device it just goes with whichever activity is declared first in the manifest. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have     <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" /> in the manifest?

Comment: I've got the following in my manifest for leanback support: 
    <!-- required for tv -->
    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v17.leanback"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" />

Comment: how are you testing your app? On emulator or actual TV?

Comment: Did you eventually overcome this issue?

Comment: @JorgeAmVF its that long ago that I don't really remember. It might have been because I was using a fire tv (aka the amazon version) which didn't use the leanback filter

Comment: It's good that you mentioned that because I'm using a very similar model as you were and I suspect it's something with the emulator (no TV to test).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution for me was to create 2 launch configuration like this:

[image: new configurations]

[image: How to configure]

Answer (score 2):

For those who still faces this poblem in 2022.
The trick is that running the app by Android Studio does not behave same as when real apk file is deployed to a real device.
So your steps are:

1. Do everything correctly in manifest, as said in [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start#tv-activity)
2. Relax and code.

Android Studio runs always first: activty with DEFAULT & LAUNCHER or LEANBACK_LAUNCHER filters. If no DEFAULT flag is set, AS will just grab first launcher activity mentioned in the manifest.
That's because **AS is unable to detect what sort of device it is deploying to**.
You can ensure your app will correctly switch launcher activity for appropriate device by generating apk file and **installing it manually**. That's how I revealed all of this.

For development purposes only you can either switch the order of launcher activities in the manifest(bad way), or to make separate run/debug configurations as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68476429/11764886) (the good way)

Comment: I want believe this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same Activity name `MainActivity` to call both your TV and Phone App. Change one of these names and you should be good to go. As shown [here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html) in the first step, your activity name for the TV should be different than your activity name for the phone app.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that doesnt make a difference

Comment: Sorry about that. Can you share more of your Manifest so we could see what might be going wrong? Nothing else seems wrong from what I see.