# Can we have a launcher activity and a lean_back launcher activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tv

Is it possible to have two activities, one that opens up on phone and the other that opens on TV devices? I want to have a separate activity for phone and TV. I have the below xml in my AndroidManifest.xml. However, when I run the app on TV emulator, it still opens up LandingScreenActivity.

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.login.LandingScreenActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
            android:name=".ui.tv.TVMainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep one activity as launcher. As soon as activity opened you can check device type . If device is TV then you can open screen for TV and clear previous screen.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing_screen);
        UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE);
        if (uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, TVMainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

    }
```

You can check this - [Android TV not starting LAUNCH_LEANBACK Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298009/android-tv-not-starting-launch-leanback-activity)